# Sylius not loading taxons on product edit

Tags: php, sylius

I have a problem in Sylius administration. When I go to edit a product and go to the tab Taxons the loading is spinning and spinning, in console I get an error `API: No URL specified for api event`. It worked before and I didn't touched the admin source code.

I honestly don't know, how to fix it and even where to start with debugging it.

Sylius version: 1.3.3

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I think it was caused by wrong assets, try to generate them again or create new Sylius project on the same version and use it's assets.

Comment: Yes.. Recreating assets did the fix. Thanks.